# Probability question, combinatorics between two different situations

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I was recently reading a text book on probability, I take it in the Spring. One thing I had trouble under standing was the ideological or just logical difference between two different problems in other words how is the setup different in the two and what are the hints in the working of the situations that call for a different method of counting:

The first one was there is a committee consisting of 3 freshman, 4 sophomores, 5 juniors and two seniors. A sub committee consisting of 4 from each class is to be chosen, how many possibilities are there?

$3\times4\times5\times2=120$

The are 10 chess competitors 4 are russian 3 are us 2 are great britian and 1 is brazil. If the tournament just results the nationalities of the players in the order in which they are placed how man outcomes are possible?

$\frac{10!}{4!3!2!1!}$ is the answer

My problem is they are both orderings and different combinations. Why is it that the second one is a ratio but the first isnt. Now I could just got by the fact that I am first given the total number of experiments (10) and answer any question like that accordingly but that is a bad way of doing it. Its very important that I understand why.

Comment: What does "If the tournament just results the nationalities of the players in the order in which they are placed" mean?

Comment: For that matter, how can I choose $4$ freshmen, say, from a group that only has $3$?

Comment: @lulu How many ways can you place 4 Russian flags, 3 US flags, etc. in a row

Comment: @angryavian  really?  I mean...it generates the proposed answer, but it seems like a stretch from the phrasing.

Comment: @lulu: It’s a committee of four, one from each class.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  Ah, of course.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > The first one was there is a committee consisting of 3 freshman, 4 sophomores, 5 juniors and two seniors. A sub committee consisting of 4 from each class is to be chosen, how many possibilities are there?

We wish to count distinct ways to select a set of *one member each* from each of *four sets* of *unique* individuals.   As you know, the ways to select $r$ elements from a *set* of size $n$ is counted as $n!/(r!\,(n-r)!)$.   Also denoted $^n\mathrm C_r$.   Thus what we wish is:

$$\frac{3!}{1!\,2!}\frac{4!}{1!\,3!}\frac{5!}{1!\,4!}\frac{2!}{1!\,1!} ~=~ 3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 1$$

> > The are 10 chess competitors 4 are russian 3 are us 2 are great britian and 1 is brazil. If the tournament just results the nationalities of the players in the order in which they are placed how man outcomes are possible?

We wish to count the ways to *arrange* a *list* of elements selected without replacement from a *multiset*.   This does not concern the identity of the individuals, merely their equivalence class (spec: the nationality).   We are also interested in counting distinct order the selections can be made.   Another way to look at this, is that we wish you count ways to select places for each nationality in a line-up.

As you know the way to select $r$ *places* from $n$ *places*, in a list, is $n!/(r!~(n-r)!)$.   So the ways to select $4$ from $10$ places, then $3$ from the unclaimed $6$, $2$ from the remaining $3$, and finally $1$ from the last unclaimed place, is:$$\frac{10!}{4!\,6!}\frac{6!}{3!\,3!}\frac{3!}{2!\,1!}\frac{1!}{1!\,0!} = \frac{10!}{4!\,3!\,2!\,1!} = 12\,600$$

> Why is it that the second one is a ratio but the first isn't.

They are both integer values obtained by division of factorials.   One was just more obviously so than the other.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a simpler example will clarify it better...

You have 1 silver spoon, 1 gold spoon and one cup.  How many ways you can pair a spoon and a cup?

```
(S1,C) or (S2,C)
```

Ignoring the material of the spoon, how may different ways you can put them all in a row?

```
(S,S,C)
(S,C,S)
(C,S,S)
```